# Javascript array value is undefined ... how do I test for that

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I am trying to test to see whether a Javascript variable is undefined.

You will see that I am not expecting the value of predQuery[preId] to be 'undefined' if I don't first get an alert saying "its unbelievable". But I often do, so I am guessing that my statement

```
 predQuery[preId]=='undefined')
```

is not matching the undefined elements properly.

```
if((predQuery.length < preId) || (predQuery[preId]=="") || (predQuery[preId]=='undefined')){
   alert("its unbelievable");
   alert(predQuery[preId]);
   queryPreds[variables] = preId;
   queryObjs[variables] = objId;
   predQuery[preId] = variables;
}
else {
    alert(predQuery[preId]);
   var predIndex = predQuery[preId];
   queryPreds[predIndex] = preId;
   queryObjs[predIndex] = objId;
}
```

I can add more code if needed.

Comment: I have used (typeof(predQuery[preId])=='undefined') as my clause in my if statement.

Comment: @deceze ... I meant that, I have changed my code. I haven't edited the question however as that won't help future people with the same problem.

Comment: I see, sorry for the misunderstanding. :o)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`array[index] == 'undefined'` compares the *value* of the array index to the string "undefined".
You're probably looking for `typeof array[index] == 'undefined'`, which compares the *type*.

Comment: +1 comparing against the immutable type instead of the mutable `undefined`

Comment: This alone cannot distinguish between `[undefined][0]` and `[][0]`. If there's any chance that your array could be empty, you will likely encounter this scenario.

Comment: Why not `array[index] === undefined`

Answer (score 15):

You are checking it the array index contains a string `"undefined"`, you should either use the `typeof` operator:

```
typeof predQuery[preId] == 'undefined'
```

Or use the `undefined` global property:

```
predQuery[preId] === undefined
```

The first way is *safer*, because the `undefined` global property is writable, and it can be changed to any other value.

Answer (score 9):

```
predQuery[preId]=='undefined'
```

You're testing against the *string* `'undefined'`; you've confused this test with the `typeof` test which would return a string. You probably mean to be testing against the special value `undefined`:

```
predQuery[preId]===undefined
```

Note the strict-equality operator to avoid the generally-unwanted match `null==undefined`.

However there are two ways you can get an `undefined` value: either `preId` isn't a member of `predQuery`, or it *is* a member but has a value set to the special `undefined` value. Often, you only want to check whether it's present or not; in that case the `in` operator is more appropriate:

```
!(preId in predQuery)
```

Answer (score 4):

There are more (many) ways to Rome:

```
//=>considering predQuery[preId] is undefined:
predQuery[preId] === undefined; //=> true
undefined === predQuery[preId] //=> true
predQuery[preId] || 'it\'s unbelievable!' //=> it's unbelievable
var isdef = predQuery[preId] ? predQuery[preId] : null //=> isdef = null
```

cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Check for

```
if (predQuery[preId] === undefined)
```

Use the strict equal to operator. See **[comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)**

Comment: almost - but best practice is as deceze says, compare typeof because that cannot be redefined as undefined can be.

Comment: Not foolproof, as undefined can be defined.  Simply with `window.undefined="lolz";`

Comment: It's impossible to write JavaScript that guards against every builtin being redefined (almost anything can be). I don't advocate making code less readable just to avoid redefinitions. `typeof` does have another use, to detect datatypes in cross-window scripting, but that doesn't apply to `undefined` anyway.

Comment: ES5 enforces `undefined` as readonly.

Answer (score 2):

try: `typeof(predQuery[preId])=='undefined'`
or more generally: `typeof(yourArray[yourIndex])=='undefined'`
You're comparing "undefined" to undefined, which returns false =)

Answer (score 1):

This code works very well

```
function isUndefined(array, index) {
    return ((String(array[index]) == "undefined") ? "Yes" : "No");
}
```

Comment: Why do you use == instead of === ?