# array value is undefined … how do I test for that

Tags: arrays, reactjs, undefined

[Javascript array value is undefined ... how do I test for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673147/javascript-array-value-is-undefined-how-do-i-test-for-that)

and

[How to check a not-defined variable in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858181/how-to-check-a-not-defined-variable-in-javascript)

these are wrong as far as I'm concerned :

I ONLY get :
[image: error]

when trying to :

```
console.log(!fromToParameters[7].value.firstInput);
console.log(!!fromToParameters[7].value.firstInput);
console.log(fromToParameters[7].value.firstInput === undefined);
console.log(typeof fromToParameters[7].value.firstInput == 'undefined');
console.log(fromToParameters[7].value.firstInput !== undefined);
console.log(typeof fromToParameters[7].value.firstInput != 'undefined');
```

but this (the entry exists) works fine :

```
console.log(!fromToParameters[0].value.firstInput);
console.log(!!fromToParameters[0].value.firstInput);
console.log(fromToParameters[0].value.firstInput === undefined);
console.log(typeof fromToParameters[0].value.firstInput == 'undefined');
console.log(fromToParameters[0].value.firstInput !== undefined);
console.log(typeof fromToParameters[0].value.firstInput != 'undefined');
```

false
true
false
true
false
true

is it a question of react being different from js? why can't I do the same as in these stackoverflow threads?

UPDATE :

so you cannot point to a missing array element at all.

Check answers below.

I think I'll be using an array.lenght stored in a const that I then check my increment against it within my "for" loop to allow or disallow modifying my array entries on a case-by-case basis.

it's really annoying that you can't just ask js if a damn var of an unexisting  array index exists or not.

it seems like this would be straightforward stuff : can't point to the index? then NO. no not this variable nor any other variable exists at this index. end of.

the guys at js definitely should put in a note for adding something as simple as this.

I'm tempted to post my code as I have something that allows for me to do what I want (calling a index with lots of undefineds and getting a object with ""s instead) but it's a bit monstrous.

Comment: You sure the size of `fromToParameters` is at least 8?

Comment: it's not it's under. how do I test a variable value for an array pointer that doesn't exist? that's what I need to have.

Comment: Wait.  Wait wait wait.  You can't index into position 7 if `fromToParameters` is not at least 8 entities long.  You literally *can't* do it.  What ***specifically*** are you trying to test for?

Comment: these variables are going to exist and need to be filled with " " if they do not exist AKA if the index doesn't go that high. how do I test for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like this:

```
console.log(fromToParameters[7] && fromToParameters[7].value.firstInput);
console.log(!!fromToParameters[7] && fromToParameters[7].value.firstInput);
console.log( fromToParameters[7]&& typeof fromToParameters[7].value.firstInput == 'undefined');
```

I have just added check. So if `fromToParameters[7]` is `undefined` or `null`, your code will not break.

Comment: it does break though. I don't know what you're testing in but it's not reactjs. in anycase I'm going to be using `if`s on the `length` of my arrays to allow or not my attribution of variable within my `for` loop. it should do the job except that means I account nowhere for the variables somehow ending up as `undefined`. there's apparently no way to handle that.

Comment: @tatsu I have updated my answer. removed leading `!`. And what do you mean by ` it's not reactjs`. Is reacts  not javascript?

Comment: ok. that's actually good : first returns `undefined` second returns `false` ( : > finally ) and last one breaks: `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`.

Comment: @tatsu you are correct.  I have  updated my the answer.

Comment: no. it's returning `undefined`. as it should, right?

Answer (score 1):

Check for the index first (ex: console.log(!yourArray[x]), then depending if that test passes or fails, access/add the indexes/properties you want.

Comment: that doesn't work either that just always returns true no matter what number on the array I feed it.

Comment: It should return false if the index exists and return true if the index doesn't exist.

Comment: well it doesn't. are you testing this in a reactjs app?

Comment: Yes this is in a react app. How are you testing it? Are you testing 'fromToParameters[7]' or 'fromToParameters[7].value.firstInput'. Before you access any of the properties of 'fromToParameters[7]', just use the index ('fromToParameters[7]') without accessing any properties to check if the index is valid.

Comment: Oh! my bad you're absolutely right with just `console.log(!fromToParameters[7]);` it works